# Add link to a anchor tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have not done anything. But like to ask if there is any way I can achieve this feature.

I have a loop in my WordPress site whose output is something like this:

```
<div class="dummy">
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

Here you can notice all the URL are same.

So what I want to know here is, if there is a way I can redirect the 3rd or 4th anchor tag to a different URL like http://facebook.com using javascript?

If there is any such way possible, please let me know. I am curious about that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give `id` to each anchor tag.

```
<div class="dummy">
    <a id="anchor_1" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a id="anchor_2" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a id="anchor_3" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a id="anchor_4" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a id="anchor_5" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

Then use following javascript code to pick desired element and change its `href` property.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("anchor_5").href = "http://www.facebook.com";
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If your website contains only these anchor tags, then you can get all the anchor tags and then select the last one ( or any other desired ) using index.

Here is a sample code

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var lastAnchor = anchors[(anchors.length - 1)];
```

In other case if you want the list of anchor tags of this particular div. (Assuming that there is only one `div` having this class name)

```
var ancestor = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy')[0];
var descendents = ancestor.getElementsByTagName('a');
descendents[4].href="http://facebook.com"
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if there is some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the `a` tag you want to change, using whatever method makes the most sense, and literally just `element.href = "www.example.com"`

```js
var first = document.getElementById("first");
first.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

```html
<div class="dummy">
    <a id="first" href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Text Here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Adam, Thanks for your reply. The complete code is coming from a PHP loop. So it is hardly a way I can add a special class to one anchor tag.

Comment: Yes, you will have to select the `a` tag in the way that makes the most sense for your application, I was just selecting it with an `id` for example sake. You'll have to grab the tag in a more dynamic way, probably by selecting all the children of `dummy` and looping through them to set each one or something like that.

Comment: But once you have it, all you have to do is set the property.